# ubuntu 13.04 no sound

Tags: 13.04, sound

After my last restart the sound is not working...

I tried this [script](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh), but I don't know how to read the output and how to fix the problem.

I tried [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) too, but it doesn't work.

What's wrong?

It's not hardware related since it works on windows 8.

Moreover, 
while trying all that, I've lost the sound-settings widget on the top-bar. 
And my sound output has turned to dummy!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo service pulseaudio restart`. Also try restarting if you haven't already done so.